# typesetting source code (Funnelweb), 2nd attempt

Tags: tex-core, code

Second version of [question about Funnelweb and funny ASCII codes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350747/typesetting-source-code-funnelweb).

ADDED: here is my input (Funnelweb file).

```
@p typesetter = tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
@$@<Example@>==@{ABC@^D(025)@}
@O@<ex.txt@>==@{@-
@<Example@>
@}
\end{document}
```

And here is the full, minimal example of the auto-generated Latex.

```
\tolerance=10000
\parindent=0pt
\def\fwparskipon{\parskip=\medskipamount}
\def\fwparskipoff{\parskip=0pt}
\fwparskipon
\raggedbottom
\font\fwfontnote=cmr7
\font\fwfontnorm=cmr10
\font\fwfontnorma=cmr10 scaled \magstep1
\font\fwfontnormb=cmr10 scaled \magstep2
\font\fwfontbold=cmbx10
\font\fwfontbolda=cmbx10 scaled \magstep1
\font\fwfontboldb=cmbx10 scaled \magstep2
\font\fwfontboldc=cmbx10 scaled \magstep3
\font\fwfontboldd=cmbx10 scaled \magstep4
\def\fwbeginmacro{\fwparskipoff\bigskip}
\def\fwendmacro{\fwparskipon\par}
\def\fwmacroname#1#2{{\sl #1\/}$\lbrack$#2$\rbrack$}
\def\fwfilename#1#2{{\bf #1}$\lbrack$#2$\rbrack$}
\def\fwzero#1{{\bf Z}}
\def\fwmany#1{{\bf M}}
\def\fwlib#1{{\bf L}}
\def\fwequals{ $\equiv$}
\def\fwplusequals{ $+\equiv$}
\def\fwodef{\parindent=15pt\vskip0pt$\lbrace$\parindent=20pt}
\def\fwcdef{$\rbrace$\vskip0pt\parindent=0pt}
\def\fwoquote{`}
\def\fwcquote{'}
\def\fwoparen{$($}
\def\fwcomma{$,$}
\def\fwcparen{$)$}
\def\fwparam#1{$\diamond #1$}
\def\fwparams#1{$(\diamond #1)$}
\def\fwbeginmacronotes{\begingroup\baselineskip=9pt\smallskip}
\def\fwnote#1{{\fwfontnote #1}\par}
\def\fwisafile#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwusedin#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwseealso#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwendmacronotes{\endgroup}
{\catcode`\`=\active \gdef`{\relax\lq}}
{\obeyspaces\global\let =\ }
\def\fwbtx[{%
\begingroup%
\def\par{\leavevmode\endgraf}%
\catcode`\`=\active%
\obeylines%
\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials%
\obeyspaces
\parskip=0pt%
\tt%
\fwverbatimgobble}
\def\fwverbatimgobble#1]fwetx={#1\endgroup}
\def\fwrule{\medskip\hrule\medskip}
\def\fwqh{\hskip1.5em\relax}
\def\fwbeforesec{\penalty-200\bigskip\medskip\par}
\def\fwtocstart#1{\fwrule\leftline{\fwfontbolda Table of Contents}\fwrule}
\def\fwtoca#1#2{\leftline{{\bf #1 #2}}}
\def\fwtocb#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocc#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocd#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtoce#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocfinish#1{\fwrule}
\def\fwliba#1#2{\vfill\eject{\fwfontboldc #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibb#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\fwfontboldb #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibc#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\fwfontnormb #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibd#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\bf          #1 #2}\penalty200}
\def\fwlibe#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\bf          #1 #2}}
\def\fwseca#1#2{\fwliba{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecb#1#2{\fwlibb{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecc#1#2{\fwlibc{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecd#1#2{\fwlibd{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsece#1#2{\fwlibe{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwlit#1{{\tt #1}}
\def\fwemp#1{{\it #1}}
\def\fwnewpage{\vfill\eject}
\def\fwvskip#1{\null\vskip #1mm}
\def\fwfontnormal#1{{\fwfontnorm {#1}}}
\def\fwfonttitle#1{{\fwfontboldd {#1}}}
\def\fwfontsmalltitle#1{{\fwfontboldb {#1}}}
\def\fwleftline#1{\leftline{#1}}
\def\fwcenterline#1{\centerline{#1}}
\def\fwrightline#1{\rightline{#1}}
\def\p#1{{\tt #1}}  % P for Program text.
\def\flagpage#1#2{
   \null
   \vfill
   \centerline{\fwfontboldd #1}
   \vskip 1cm
   \centerline{\fwfontboldd #2}
   \vfill
   \null
   \vfill
}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fwbeginmacro
\fwmacroname{Example}{1}\fwequals \fwodef \fwbtx[ABC]fwetx=%
\fwcdef 
\fwbeginmacronotes
\fwusedin{This macro is invoked in definition 2.}
\fwendmacronotes
\fwendmacro
\fwbeginmacro
\fwfilename{ex.txt}{2}\fwequals \fwodef \fwmacroname{Example}{1}\fwbtx[
]fwetx=%
\fwcdef 
\fwbeginmacronotes
\fwisafile{This macro is attached to an output file.}
\fwendmacronotes
\fwendmacro
\end{document}
\bye
```

And here is the error

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.97 ...Example}{1}\fwequals \fwodef \fwbtx[ABC^^Y
                                                  ]fwetx=%
```

Ideally, I would like to only have to replace one macro definition, not add any new things.

Comment: You could have edited your other question as well, there's no need to post the same question twice

Comment: And you still aren't saying what should `^Y` produce.

Comment: Yes, will edit question next time. Well ^Y is what ASCII code 25 looks like in the editor/shell. It is not supposed to produce anything. It has to be there in the C code, and it has (I thought) to be escaped in the Tex code. So the question is (I currently believe, with maybe 50% certainty) why is that character not escaped? Escaped as in replaced with a blank space or something.

Comment: You should not use `\bf`. This is plainTeX or LaTeX 2.09 code. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{…}`. And you should not use `\font` commands. Use the [font selection commands of LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. But I did not write it...

Comment: can you delete your previous question. I get no error from this code, probably the web site interface stripped the control character,

Comment: Arg. I've already answered the other question in hope this question will become a duplicate and the first question will become the primary.

Comment: @Schweinebacke as this one has a usable example why don't you copy your answer here then we can close that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website strips  control characters but I added one between square brackets in one text and added two lines at the top so it prints safely. Change **CONTROL-Y** to whatever you want

I realise it is generated code but it is pretty horrible, the tex generator really should be updated:-)

[image]

```
\catcode25=13 \def^^Y{CONTROL-Y}
\tolerance=10000
\parindent=0pt
\def\fwparskipon{\parskip=\medskipamount}
\def\fwparskipoff{\parskip=0pt}
\fwparskipon
\raggedbottom
\font\fwfontnote=cmr7
\font\fwfontnorm=cmr10
\font\fwfontnorma=cmr10 scaled \magstep1
\font\fwfontnormb=cmr10 scaled \magstep2
\font\fwfontbold=cmbx10
\font\fwfontbolda=cmbx10 scaled \magstep1
\font\fwfontboldb=cmbx10 scaled \magstep2
\font\fwfontboldc=cmbx10 scaled \magstep3
\font\fwfontboldd=cmbx10 scaled \magstep4
\def\fwbeginmacro{\fwparskipoff\bigskip}
\def\fwendmacro{\fwparskipon\par}
\def\fwmacroname#1#2{{\sl #1\/}$\lbrack$#2$\rbrack$}
\def\fwfilename#1#2{{\bf #1}$\lbrack$#2$\rbrack$}
\def\fwzero#1{{\bf Z}}
\def\fwmany#1{{\bf M}}
\def\fwlib#1{{\bf L}}
\def\fwequals{ $\equiv$}
\def\fwplusequals{ $+\equiv$}
\def\fwodef{\parindent=15pt\vskip0pt$\lbrace$\parindent=20pt}
\def\fwcdef{$\rbrace$\vskip0pt\parindent=0pt}
\def\fwoquote{`}
\def\fwcquote{'}
\def\fwoparen{$($}
\def\fwcomma{$,$}
\def\fwcparen{$)$}
\def\fwparam#1{$\diamond #1$}
\def\fwparams#1{$(\diamond #1)$}
\def\fwbeginmacronotes{\begingroup\baselineskip=9pt\smallskip}
\def\fwnote#1{{\fwfontnote #1}\par}
\def\fwisafile#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwusedin#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwseealso#1{\fwnote{#1}}
\def\fwendmacronotes{\endgroup}
{\catcode`\`=\active \gdef`{\relax\lq}}
{\obeyspaces\global\let =\ }
\def\fwbtx[{%
\begingroup%
\def\par{\leavevmode\endgraf}%
\catcode`\`=\active%
\obeylines%
\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials%
\obeyspaces
\parskip=0pt%
\tt%
\fwverbatimgobble}
\def\fwverbatimgobble#1]fwetx={#1\endgroup}
\def\fwrule{\medskip\hrule\medskip}
\def\fwqh{\hskip1.5em\relax}
\def\fwbeforesec{\penalty-200\bigskip\medskip\par}
\def\fwtocstart#1{\fwrule\leftline{\fwfontbolda Table of Contents}\fwrule}
\def\fwtoca#1#2{\leftline{{\bf #1 #2}}}
\def\fwtocb#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocc#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocd#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtoce#1#2{\leftline{\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh\fwqh #1 #2}}
\def\fwtocfinish#1{\fwrule}
\def\fwliba#1#2{\vfill\eject{\fwfontboldc #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibb#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\fwfontboldb #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibc#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\fwfontnormb #1 #2}\penalty200\smallskip}
\def\fwlibd#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\bf          #1 #2}\penalty200}
\def\fwlibe#1#2{\fwbeforesec{\bf          #1 #2}}
\def\fwseca#1#2{\fwliba{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecb#1#2{\fwlibb{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecc#1#2{\fwlibc{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsecd#1#2{\fwlibd{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwsece#1#2{\fwlibe{#1}{#2}}
\def\fwlit#1{{\tt #1}}
\def\fwemp#1{{\it #1}}
\def\fwnewpage{\vfill\eject}
\def\fwvskip#1{\null\vskip #1mm}
\def\fwfontnormal#1{{\fwfontnorm {#1}}}
\def\fwfonttitle#1{{\fwfontboldd {#1}}}
\def\fwfontsmalltitle#1{{\fwfontboldb {#1}}}
\def\fwleftline#1{\leftline{#1}}
\def\fwcenterline#1{\centerline{#1}}
\def\fwrightline#1{\rightline{#1}}
\def\p#1{{\tt #1}}  % P for Program text.
\def\flagpage#1#2{
   \null
   \vfill
   \centerline{\fwfontboldd #1}
   \vskip 1cm
   \centerline{\fwfontboldd #2}
   \vfill
   \null
   \vfill
}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fwbeginmacro
\fwmacroname{Example}{1}\fwequals \fwodef \fwbtx[ABC]fwetx=%
\fwcdef 
\fwbeginmacronotes
\fwusedin{This macro is invoked in definition 2.}
\fwendmacronotes
\fwendmacro
\fwbeginmacro
\fwfilename{ex.txt}{2}\fwequals \fwodef \fwmacroname{Example}{1}\fwbtx[
]fwetx=%
\fwcdef 
\fwbeginmacronotes
\fwisafile{This macro is attached[] to an output file.}
\fwendmacronotes
\fwendmacro
\end{document}
\bye
```

Comment: Well, you seem to have just removed the offending character? That doesn't really solve the problem, as it has to be there in the C code. In literate programming, the tool generates two outputs: source code and (for example) Latex, from the same input. I cannot change the input, and the C code is fine. What I need to do is get the Latex to handle the same input, including this ASCII code 25 character. The stuff that is a parameter to the "fwbtx" macro is the version of the source code destined for the printed document. The code I posted above is the auto-generated Latex version.

Comment: @TomasBy No the control Y is in the input between `[]` where it is marked with a red circle in the image, _this web site_ removed the control character from your question so I had to guess where to add one and of course it is removed again from my answer. Just add the line I added at the top and ^Y will be safe.

Comment: Sorry I am not following. I copied your code and did a diff. Ok, hang on, will check. Ok, thanks, it seems to work.

Comment: @TomasBy Look at the image I posed where it says CONTROL-Y the source for that was where I added the character 25  as `... attached[^Y] to ...` but the website is removing all control characters so there is no character 25 in your question (it runs without error) nor my answer. But if you add the line `\catcode25=13 \def^^Y{CONTROL-Y}` to your file then ^Y will be made safe

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand. I only need to add that line somewhere. It doesn't have to be at top, only before begin{document}. Great. Thank you!